# Exporting Selenium-IDE source code to JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Can Selenium-IDE export source code to JavaScript code?
I tried to write test with webdriverjs using nodejs. I hope to use converted code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-html-js-converter).
But this way, I think you can only use phantomjs, unless you can configure manually to work with others.